PysimpleGUI creates plots under previous plots
In the below code my attempted work flow is:
1.) to browse for the selected geotiff and shapefile.
2.) click the 'Plot Me' button which will plot the two files together.
3.) click the 'Export Me' button which will trim the geotiff around the shapefile and provide
locations to save the created trimmed geotiff.
4.) click the 'refresh' button which will remove the file paths for the geotiff and shapefile browser to get ready for another set of files.
5.) repeat steps 1-4 for however many files that would want to be trimmed.
Everything seems to be working correctly except when I try to repeat the plot function (step 5.) the code is plotting a new geotiff/shapefile plot below the previous one instead of on top of the previous plot. See below:

import PySimpleGUI as sg
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import geopandas as gpd
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from shapely.geometry import mapping
import rioxarray as rxr
import matplotlib.colors as mcolors
import numpy as np

# Inside plot_geospatial_data function:
def plot_geospatial_data(geotiff_path, shapefile_path, canvas_elem, window, figsize):
    # Read GeoTIFF
    geotiff = rxr.open_rasterio(geotiff_path)

    # Read Shapefile
    shapefile = gpd.read_file(shapefile_path)

    # Reproject GeoTIFF to match Shapefile CRS
    geotiff = geotiff.rio.reproject(shapefile.crs)

    # Get the spatial extent of the GeoTIFF
    xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax = geotiff.rio.bounds()

    # Extract elevation values from the GeoTIFF
    elevation_values = geotiff.values.flatten()

    # Find the minimum non-zero elevation value greater than 0
    min_elevation = np.min(elevation_values[(elevation_values > 0)])

    # Plot GeoTIFF with terrain colormap starting from min_elevation
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(7.7, 4.4))
    plt.imshow(geotiff.squeeze(), extent=[xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax], cmap='terrain', norm=mcolors.Normalize(vmin=min_elevation))
    
    # Plot Shapefile outline
    shapefile.plot(ax=plt.gca(), edgecolor='red', alpha=0.7, linewidth=1, facecolor='none')

    plt.title('GeoTiff/Shapefile Plot')
    plt.xlabel('Longitude')
    plt.ylabel('Latitude')
    plt.grid(True)

    # Show the plot on the canvas
    canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(plt.gcf(), master=canvas_elem.Widget)
    canvas.draw()
    canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(fill='both', expand=1)

    return plt.gcf()

def trim_function(existing_surface_path, fill_boundary_path, output_path_elem):
    # Open the GeoTIFF using rioxarray
    existing_surface = rxr.open_rasterio(existing_surface_path, masked=True).squeeze()
    
    # Open Shapefile
    aoi = os.path.join(fill_boundary_path)
    crop_extent = gpd.read_file(aoi)

    # Reproject GeoTIFF to match Shapefile CRS
    existing_surface = existing_surface.rio.reproject(crop_extent.crs)

    # Crop the Existing Surface using rioxarray
    fill_surface = existing_surface.rio.clip(crop_extent.geometry.apply(mapping), crop_extent.crs)

    # Convert elevation values from meters to feet
    fill_surface.data = fill_surface.data * 3.28084  # Conversion factor from meters to feet

    # Ask the user to select an output file path
    output_path = sg.popup_get_file("Select Output Path", save_as=True, file_types=(("GeoTIFF Files", "*.tif"),))

    # If the user selected an output path, ensure it has a .tif extension
    if output_path:
        if not output_path.endswith(".tif"):
            output_path += ".tif"

        # Export the trimmed surface as a GeoTIFF
        fill_surface.rio.to_raster(output_path, driver="GTiff", crs=crop_extent.crs)
        
# Define the layout of the GUI window
layout = [
    [sg.Frame("Data Selection", layout=[
        [
            sg.Column([
                [sg.Text("Select a GeoTIFF file: ", font=("Helvetica", 14))],
                [sg.Text("Select a Shapefile file:", font=("Helvetica", 14))],
            ]),
            sg.Column([
                [sg.InputText(key="geotiff_path", size=(60, 1)), sg.FileBrowse(file_types=(("GeoTIFF Files", "*.tif"),))],
                [sg.InputText(key="shapefile_path", size=(60, 1)), sg.FileBrowse(file_types=(("Shapefile Files", "*.shp"),))],
            ])
        ]
    ], expand_x=True)],
    [sg.Canvas(key="canvas", background_color="white", size=(770, 400))],
    [sg.Button("Plot Me", key="plot_button", size=(10, 1), font=("Helvetica", 14)), sg.Text('', size=(65, 1)), sg.Button("Export Me", key="export_button", visible=False, size=(10, 1), font=("Helvetica", 14))],  # Place both buttons in the same row with an empty Text element in between
    [sg.Button("Refresh", key="refresh_button", size=(10, 1), font=("Helvetica", 14))]
]

# Create the GUI window
window = sg.Window("CropMe", layout, finalize=True, size=(800, 600))
canvas_elem = window["canvas"]  # Initialize canvas_elem
current_plot = None
while True:
    event, values = window.read()

    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break
    if event == "plot_button":
        geotiff_path = values["geotiff_path"]
        shapefile_path = values["shapefile_path"]
        if geotiff_path and shapefile_path:
            if current_plot is not None:
                plt.close(current_plot)
            current_plot = plot_geospatial_data(geotiff_path, shapefile_path, canvas_elem, window, figsize=(11, 5))
            window["export_button"].Update(visible=True)  # Show the export button after plotting

    if event == "refresh_button":
        window["geotiff_path"].update('')
        window["shapefile_path"].update('')
        if current_plot is not None:
            plt.close(current_plot)
        plt.figure(figsize=(7.7, 4.4))
        plt.gca().set_facecolor('white')
        plt.draw()
        plt.pause(0.001)
        current_plot = plt.gcf()

    window.read(timeout=0)  # Force a GUI refresh

window.close()


Each call to FigureCanvasTkAgg will create a new canvas in the Canvas element, and placed from top to bottom. You should call it only once and clear the figure by matplotlib code, then redraw, to get a new figure on the same canvas.

Adding to Jason's comment... maybe this Demo Program could be of help.  Over the years, the techniques for working with PySimpleGUI + Matplotlib has evolved (and continues to)
